# Property similar to decreasingness

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{ a_j \}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ be any sequence of real numbers satisfying the following property:

> There exists a number $N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $a_k<a_j$ for all
>   $k\geq j+N$.

What is such a sequence called?

If $N=1$, $\{a_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is of course an decreasing sequence.

One example of such a sequence with N=2 is -1,0,-2,-1,-3,-2,-4,-3,...

Comment: Isn't it *decreasing* if $N=1$? You have $k\gt j$ implies $a_k\lt a_j$.

Comment: Typo :) It should now be correct